# How to hightlight matching text from result set when I type something in HTML textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**index.php page with textbox to search**

```
<form role="form" name="frm_add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {
        $( "#txt_itemname" ).autocomplete({
            source: './search.php'
        });
    });
    </script>
                                       
    <input type="text" id="txt_itemname" name="txt_itemname">
    <button type="submit"><i class='fas fa-search'></i>&nbsp;</button>
</form>
```

**When user types something then matching text coming from search.php**

```
- Fetching API data in `$result` using cURL PHP
$json = json_decode($result, true); 
$arr_searchTerm = array(); 

if (is_array($json) && !empty($json))
{
    foreach($json as $key1 => $level1)
    {
        array_push($arr_searchTerm, $level1['Name']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr_searchTerm); 
exit();
```

This is example array values `array("Apple", "Lenovo", "LG", "Nokia", "Samsung", "Sony");`

My above search code on both index.php and search.php is working fine. Now I want to do following things either using PHP, Javascript or jQuery.

- If user types `s` in textbox then 2 words Sony & Samsung are displayed in drop down list (This part is working fine right now). So now I want to make so char `s` of Sony and Samsung in drop down list should be highlighted in different color.
- I want to show some `Cookies` data when user clicks in textbox and these cookies data should be displayed in textbox drop down when user clicks in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your data is an object, so that is reason your code not working, try to make sure your data is an array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
   c = c.substring(1);
  }
 if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
   return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
 }
}
return "";
}

var yourVar = getCookie("yourCookieName");
```

you must declare your search.php value into a variable then merge with your cookie, you can using ajax for get search.php value.

Comment: Displaying data in drop down when type something is working fine. I need help on 2 things I mentioned in my question. Ty

Comment: That will be fine so please help for #2